# How to catch the mouseDoubleClickEvent event in QTreeWidgetItem?

Tags: python, pyqt

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui

class FirstInstance(QtWidgets.QTreeWidget, QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setHeaderHidden(True)
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 700, 500)

        FirstInstance = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(self, ['А1'])
        Administrative_proceedings_1 = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(FirstInstance, ['qqq'])
        QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(Administrative_proceedings_1, ['1'])
        QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(Administrative_proceedings_1, ['8'])
        QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(Administrative_proceedings_1, ['4'])
        QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(Administrative_proceedings_1, ['9'])
        QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(Administrative_proceedings_1, ['2'])
        QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(Administrative_proceedings_1, ['5'])
        QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(Administrative_proceedings_1, ['7'])

    def mouseDoubleClickEvent(self, event):
        QtWidgets.QTreeWidget.mouseDoubleClickEvent(self, event)
        print("Mouse Double Click Event")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = FirstInstance()
    window.setWindowTitle("Window")
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

If I click on "2", there should be event 2, if on "8", there should be event 8

At the same time, clicking on A1 or qqq, there should be no actions. In the future, clicking on a tree element will refer to another class

Comment: Qt docs: [QTreeWidget.itemDoubleClicked](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidget.html#itemDoubleClicked).

Comment: Sorry, I'm just new to this. How do I implement this?

Comment: This isn't a tutorial site. Please make an effort to at least [learn the basics](https://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt5/).

Comment: @Андрей Also, QTreeWidget (like ***all*** widgets) already inherits from QWidget, so remove that from the class definition and just leave QTreeWidget.

Comment: @musicamante I still can't figure out how to implement it. Can you help? On this code`
        FirstInstance = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(self, ['А1'])
        Administrative_proceedings_1 = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(FirstInstance, ['ава'])
        QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(Administrative_proceedings_1, ['1'])
        QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(Administrative_proceedings_1, ['8'])
        QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(Administrative_proceedings_1, ['4'])

        self.itemDoubleClicked.connect(self.mouseDoubleClickEvent)
    def mouseDoubleClickEvent(self, item):
        print(item.text())`

Comment: @Андрей please don't put full code in comments. Then, if you carefully read and *understand* the tutorial linked above, it's explained that signals have to be connected to the instances that emit them. `itemDoubleClicked` is a member of the tree widget instance, not `self`. Sorry, but those are basic concepts that you have to figure out on your own, as already said, this is not a tutorial website. Finally, you shall always use [layout managers](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html).